# AChartEngine: set x values in RangeBar chart series

Tags: android, achartengine

My aim is to display a RangeBar chart together with a timeChart in a CombinedChart view.
Both series show information about the same time interval. 
My problem is that I can't define the x values of the RangeBar chart. So it's values are shown all nearly 0 on the x-axis while the TimeSeries begins e.g. on value 100000 on the x-axis (DateTime in milliseconds).
I wish to define the x values from RangeBar with the x values from the TimeSeries data, but in the RangeCategorySeries you only can add minValue and MaxValue.

```
RangeCategorySeries series = new RangeCategorySeries(name);
series.add(minValue, maxValue);
```

so the x values are 0,1,2,3, ...

Do someone has an idea to solve my problem? Maybe there is another Series-class I can use for RangeBar chart where I can define also the xValue?

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeChart` has huge X axis values. That's because it actually has Date timestamps there.

In order to have several charts looking good in a `CombinedXYChart`, they must have X axis that overlap.

I suggest you use a regular `LineChart` instead of the `TimeChart` and set your custom X axis labels using `renderer.addXTextLabel();`

Comment: I think it's quite difficult to convert timestamps in low values to let them overlap with the values from RangeBar chart. Maybe you have an idea? BarChart will have max 200 datapoints. The duration of the data is about the last day or the last three days.

Comment: I've seen more difficult stuff than this.

Comment: oh sure :D sorry! it's early days yet :P

Comment: Hm adding custom labels are not nice..if you zoom out the labels are overlapping and if you zoom in you maybe don't see any label..

Comment: Then you will have to listen for zoom events and update the labels.